# Left outer join does not work for me with PySpark DataFrames

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two PySpark DataFrames `df1` and `df2`:

```
df1

col1_1   col2_1   col3_1
1        A        12
2        B        13
3        C        14 
4        D        15
5        E        16


df2
    col1_2   col2_2   col3_2
    1        A        X
    6        B        Y
    7        C        Z
```

I want to make left outer join in order to get this result:

df_joined

```
col1_1   col2_1   col3_1     col3_2
1        A        12         X
2        B        13         Null
3        C        14         Null
4        D        15         Null
5        E        16         Null
```

So, `df_joined` should have the number of rows the same as `df1`.

```
df_joined = df1.join(df2,(df1.col1_1==df2.col1_2) & (df1.col2_1==df2.col2_2),'left_outer')
```

However, I get less rows in `df_joined`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your example, the number of rows in `df1` and `df_joined` are the same, no? Both are 5.

Comment: Please post what the result with what less rows looks like.

Comment: @Shaido: yes, because I posted the expected result, while the join command returns a different result.

Comment: So what is the result you get?

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join) it states that:

```
# for more than one conditions:
cond = [df.name == df3.name, df.age == df3.age]
df.join(df3, cond, 'outer').select(df.name, df3.age).collect()
        [Row(name=u'Alice', age=2), Row(name=u'Bob', age=5)]
```

I cannot verify this currently but, does the following work for you? :

```
df_joined = df1.join(df2,[df1.col1_1==df2.col1_2, df1.col2_1==df2.col2_2],'left_outer')
```

Comment: But what's the difference? It gives me the same result.

Comment: @Dinosaurius can you post what your result looks like? (the result with less rows.)